# R: sparse matrix conversion

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix of factors in R and want to convert it to a matrix of dummy variables 0-1 for all possible levels of each factors.

However this "dummy" matrix is very large (91690x16593) and very sparse.  I need to store it in a sparse matrix, otherwise it does not fit in my 12GB of ram.

Currently, I am using the following code and it works very fine and takes seconds:

```
library(Matrix)
X_factors <- data.frame(lapply(my_matrix, as.factor))
#encode factor data in a sparse matrix
X <- sparse.model.matrix(~.-1, data = X_factors)
```

However, I want to use the e1071 package in R, and eventually save this matrix to libsvm format with `write.matrix.csr()`, so first I need to convert my sparse matrix to the **SparseM** format.

I tried to do:

```
library(SparseM)  
X2 <- as.matrix.csr(X)
```

but it very quickly fills my RAM and eventually R crashes.  I suspect that internally, `as.matrix.csr` first converts the sparse matrix to a dense matrix that does not fit in my computer memory.

My other alternative would be to create my sparse matrix directly in the SparseM format.
I tried `as.matrix.csr(X_factors)` but it does not accept a data-frame of factors.

Is there an equivalent to `sparse.model.matrix(~.-1, data = X_factors)` in the SparseM package? I searched in the documentation but I did not find.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quite tricky but I think I got it.

Let's start with a sparse matrix from the `Matrix` package:

```
i <- c(1,3:8)
j <- c(2,9,6:10)
x <- 7 * (1:7)
X <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x)
```

The `Matrix` package uses a column-oriented compression format, while `SparseM` supports both column and row oriented formats and has functions that can easily handle the conversion from one format to the other.

So we will first convert our column-oriented `Matrix` into a column-oriented `SparseM` matrix:  we just need to be careful calling the right constructor and noticing that both packages use different conventions for indices (start at `0` or `1`):

```
X.csc <- new("matrix.csc", ra = X@x,
                           ja = X@i + 1L,
                           ia = X@p + 1L,
                           dimension = X@Dim)
```

Then, change from column-oriented to row-oriented format:

```
X.csr <- as.matrix.csr(X.csc)
```

And you're done! You can check that the two matrices are identical (on my small example) by doing:

```
range(as.matrix(X) - as.matrix(X.csc))
# [1] 0 0
```