# Sparse matrix in CSC format dgCMatrix in LiblineaR occurs error [R]

Tags: r, liblinear, text2vec

dtm_train_tfidf is a sparse matrix in CSC format dgCMatrix

I am using the function LiblineaR which is supposed to accept sparse matrices. However when I use the sparse matrix dtm_train_tfidf, the following error occurs:

```
 library(LiblineaR)

 LiblineaR(data=dtm_train_tfidf,
 target=train$setiment, type = 4, cost = 1, epsilon = 0.1,
 +           svr_eps = NULL, bias = 1, cross = 0, verbose = FALSE,
 +           findC = FALSE)

 Error in t.default(data) : argument is not a matrix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LiblineaR` relies on [SparseM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparseM/index.html) package which is not mainstream now-days for sparse matrices in R. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375056/r-sparse-matrix-conversion) on how convert  `dgCMatrix` to "matrix.csc" from `SparseM`.

Comment: Hi, The link you provided in the second sentence is now dead.